# CodeIgniter URL not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I wonder if anyone can help me??? I'm using CodeIgniter to create a small Login Screen. However, every time I call the function to validate the details using the CodeIgniter form helper. A 404 error keeps showing stating that CodeIgniter can't find the URL. My code for the 'View' file looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CodeIgniter Prototype</title>

    <!-- CSS/LESS Code Links -->
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" type = "text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "login_wrapper">
        <h1>ONESG OneInvoice Exporter</h1>
        <?php
            echo form_open('login/check_login');
            echo form_input('username', '', 'placeholder = "Enter Username"');
            echo form_password('password', '', 'placeholder = "Enter Password"');
            echo form_submit('submit', 'Login');
            echo form_close();
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller Code Looks Like:

```
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('login_form');
    }

    public function check_login() {
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        $query = $this->login_model->validate();

        if ($query) {
            $data = array (
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );

            $this->sessions->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('site/members_area');
        }

        else {
            $this->index();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please post your controller code

Comment: <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

 public function index() {
  $this->load->view('login_form');
 }

 public function check_login() {
  $this->load->model('login_model');
  $query = $this->login_model->validate();

  if ($query) {
   $data = array (
    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
    'is_logged_in' => true
   );

   $this->sessions->set_userdata($data);
   redirect('site/members_area');
  }

  else {
   $this->index();
  }
 }

}

Comment: Could you please edit your question and put it there with formating. :)

Comment: do you have index.php in your url ??

Comment: So after accessing yoururl.com/index.php/Login you get 404 ?

Comment: yeah and the controller code is show above

Comment: inspect the form browser and see whats in the `action` attribute and also post your url where form is submitted and got 404

Comment: Same here. I can't see what is causing it. Is it because I'm using MAMP localhost???

Comment: Do you mean you can get to your login page, but you get a 404 when submitting the form?  If so, please post the URL you are using to access your login page.

Comment: a 404 rings the routes bell. what's your routes file like?

Comment: Yeh I get to the login page using localhost/ProjectSage but when I submit. I get the 404 error trying to access URL: http://localhost/ProjectSage/login/check_login

Comment: any my routes file looks like:              $route['default_controller'] = "login";
$route['404_override'] = '';

Comment: Thanks for your help but I worked out what the problem was. My $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; was blank when it should of look like ^^^^^^. Now I just have a problem with my code in another file lol. Thanks again guys

Answer (score 2):

Check your folder structure whether you have .htaccess file.
if not add file name called .htaccess
and add following code to file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then in routes.php in config add

```
$route["members_area/(.*)"] = 'site/members_area/$1';
```